# Passing an array of arrays as parameter to a function

Tags: arrays, postgresql, parameter-passing, postgresql-9.3

A web application can send to a function an `array of arrays` like

```js
[
    [
        [1,2],
        [3,4]
    ],
    [
        [],
        [4,5,6]
    ]
]
```

The outer array length is `n > 0`. The middle arrays are of constant length, 2 in this example. And the inner arrays lengths are `n >= 0`.

I could string build it like this:

```sql
with t(a, b) as (
    values (1, 4), (2, 3), (1, 4), (7, 3), (7, 4)
)
select distinct a, b
from t
where
    (a = any(array[1,2]) or array_length(array[1,2],1) is null)
    and
    (b = any(array[3,4]) or array_length(array[3,4],1) is null)
    or
    (a = any(array[]::int[]) or array_length(array[]::int[],1) is null)
    and
    (b = any(array[4,5,6]) or array_length(array[4,5,6],1) is null)
;
 a | b 
---+---
 7 | 4
 1 | 4
 2 | 3
```

But I think I can do better like this

```sql
with t(a, b) as (
    values (1, 4), (2, 3), (1, 4), (7, 3), (7, 4)
), u as (
    select unnest(a)::text[] as a
    from (values
        (
            array[
                '{"{1,2}", "{3,4}"}',
                '{"{}", "{4,5,6}"}'
            ]::text[]
        )
    ) s(a)
), s as (
    select a[1]::int[] as a1, a[2]::int[] as a2
    from u
)
select distinct a, b
from
    t
    inner join
    s on
        (a = any(a1) or array_length(a1, 1) is null)
        and
        (b = any(a2) or array_length(a2, 1) is null)
;
 a | b 
---+---
 7 | 4
 2 | 3
 1 | 4
```

Notice that a `text array` was passed and then "casted" inside the function. That was necessary as Postgresql can only deal with arrays of matched dimensions and the passed inner arrays can vary in dimension. I could "fix" them before passing by adding some special value like zero to make them all the same length of the longest one but I think it is cleaner to deal with that inside the function.

Am I missing something? Is it the best approach?

Comment: Is the format of the 3-dimensional array wrapped in text format given or can you chose how to pass these values? And the function receiving these values is plpgsql? Postgres version?

Comment: @Erwin I can chose how to pass the values. The front end is Python so very flexible. That format is just how I managed it to work. The function is now working in sql for simplicity but it can be plpgsql or plpython. Postgresql 9.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like your second approach.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM   (VALUES (1, 4), (5, 1), (2, 3), (1, 4), (7, 3), (7, 4)) AS t(a, b)
JOIN   (
   SELECT arr[1]::int[] AS a1
         ,arr[2]::int[] AS b1
   FROM   (
      SELECT unnest(ARRAY['{"{1,2}", "{3,4}"}'
                         ,'{"{}"   , "{4,5,6}"}'
                         ,'{"{5}"  , "{}"}'    -- added element to 1st dimension
                         ])::text[] AS arr     -- 1d text array
      ) sub
   ) s ON (a = ANY(a1) OR a1 = '{}')
      AND (b = ANY(b1) OR b1 = '{}')
;
```

Suggesting only minor improvements:

1. Subqueries instead of CTEs for slightly better performance.
2. Simplified test for empty array: checking against literal `'{}'` instead of function call.
3. One less subquery level for unwrapping the array.

Result:

```
a | b
--+---
2 | 3
7 | 4
1 | 4
5 | 1
```

For the casual reader: Wrapping the multi-dimensional array of integer is necessary, since Postgres demands that (quoting error message):

> multidimensional arrays must have array expressions with matching dimensions

An **alternate route** would be with a **2-dimensional text array** and unnest it using `generate_subscripts()`:

```
WITH a(arr) AS (SELECT '{{"{1,2}", "{3,4}"}
                        ,{"{}", "{4,5,6}"}
                        ,{"{5}", "{}"}}'::text[]   -- 2d text array
             )
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM  (VALUES (1, 4), (5, 1), (2, 3), (1, 4), (7, 3), (7, 4)) AS t(a, b)
JOIN  (
   SELECT arr[i][1]::int[] AS a1
         ,arr[i][2]::int[] AS b1
   FROM   a, generate_subscripts(a.arr, 1) i       -- using implicit LATERAL
   ) s ON (t.a = ANY(s.a1) OR s.a1 = '{}')
      AND (t.b = ANY(s.b1) OR s.b1 = '{}');
```

Might be faster, can you test?

In versions before 9.3 one would use an explicit `CROSS JOIN` instead of lateral cross joining.

Comment: Yes the `generate_subscripts` version is consistently faster in the real function. Execution time goes from 10 to 5 ms.